# Web service example

Tags: web-services

Can anyone point to live examples of SOAP or REST web services? How do you use or test an existing web service with a client?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120/example-web-service

Answer (score 4):

A SOAP webservice which converts the temperature Celsius to Fahrenheit and other way around http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

A description and source code is here http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_example.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice collection of example web services. I usually use them for experiments http://www.webservicex.net/

And for WS debug - I generate wrapper with VS and write unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, its good

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html